# Resolução da imagem no Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estive procurando alguma opção mas não encontrei de como configurar a resolução do carousel.

Vou dar um exemplo. Tenha essa imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No carousel ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma maneira de deixa-la inteira, ou uma maior parte?

Essa configuração existe no carousel? Ou tem que ser feita pelo css?

**Meu código do carousel**:

```
<section id="main-slider" class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <h1>Horticultura Sustentável</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Horticultura Sustentável</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <h1>IAC</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lala <br>lala</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
        <a class="prev" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
        <a class="next" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
    </section>
```

**CSS**:

```
#main-slider {
  background-image: url(../images/slider-bg.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 200px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Pode postar os códigos?

Comment: @Natan,postei,perdão

Comment: Aplique as classes img-rounded e img-responsive nas imagens do carousel. Se não funcionar aplique o código CSS deste JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/sefilorewu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Você pode aplicar as classes `img-rounded` e `img-responsive`.

Em alguns casos pode não funcionar, mas você pode contornar o problema sobrescrevendo o estilo padrão do bootstrap.

Você deve definir o `min-width` das imagens como `100%` pra que ele acompanhe o tamanho da sua `DIV` pai e um `position: relative` para ter a referência do `carousel-inner`.

Ficando:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position-relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* Altura da imagem dentro do Carousel */
}
```

**Exemplo no JSBIN:** http://jsbin.com/sefilorewu/1/

Comment: Cara valeu mesmo!!! Já tinha tentado de todo jeito e não conseguia redimensionar as imagens do carousel como eu queria, agora deu!